# why won't my function echo out the return arrays ive made?

Tags: php, arrays

This is just a simple script meant to split an array of integers up from odd to even, however when I try to output the two different arrays I've made, nothing is outputted to the screen.  Here is my code for example :

```
<?php
$ints = [1, 2, 3, 4];
function  getEvens($evens){
    $even_array = null;
    $odd_array = null;
    foreach ($evens  as  $value){
        if ($value / 2 == 0) {
            $even_array = array($value);

        }
        else {
            $odd_array = array($value);

        }

    }
    return  $even_array;
    return $odd_array;

}
echo  getEvens($ints);
?>
```

Comment: Only the first `return` will be executed.... `return` terminates execution of the function code and returns to the calling code

Comment: `echo` won't display the values in an array, but the word `Array`.... either loop over the array echoing the individual values; or `implode` the array to a string that can be echoed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have a single `return` statement - the second `return` will never be executed as the function ends when it reaches the first `return`. And echo on an array produces an error, you'll need to use [print_r()](http://www.php.net/print_r) or [var_dump()](http://www.php.net/var_dump).

Additionally, you are using the incorrect operator to determine if something is odd or even. Use [modulus](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).

Finally, you keep re-initializing your array rather than adding a value to it. Try this:

```
$ints = [1, 2, 3, 4];
function  getEvens($evens){
    $even_array = array();
    $odd_array = array();
    foreach ($evens  as  $value){
        if ($value % 2 == 0) {
            $even_array[] = $value;

        }
        else {
            $odd_array[] = $value;

        }

    }
    return array('even' => $even_array, 'odd' => $odd_array);

}

var_dump(getEvens($ints));
```

And finally, your result from the above is:

```
Array
(
    [even] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
        )

    [odd] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($value / 2 == 0) {
```

`$value / 2` will only ever be 0 if $value is 0

```
0/2 = 0
1/2 = 0.5
2/2 = 1
etc
```

Do you mean

```
if ($value % 2 == 0) {
```

**EDIT**

```
$even_array = array($value);
```

will always `replace` $even_array with the assigned value, so you'll only ever get the last result

Answer (score 1):

Try like below. Read the comments in the code

```
$ints = [1, 2, 3, 4];
function  getEvens($evens){
    $even_array = array(); //Declare arrays as array() instead of null
    $odd_array = array();
    foreach ($evens  as  $value){
        if ($value % 2 == 0) { //Use modulo to detect if it is even or odd
            $even_array[] = $value; // Use [] to add value to array

        }
        else {
            $odd_array[] = $value;

        }

    }

    //You can only return 1 element, So combine them in one array
    return  array(
        'even' => $even_array; 
        'odd' => $odd_array
    );

}
echo  '<pre>';
print_r(getEvens($ints));
echo  '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the operator to `%`...

```
$value =0 then only the result is 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this ?

```
<?php
$ints = array(1,2,3,4);

function  getEvens($evens){
    $even_array = null;
    $odd_array = null;

    foreach ($evens  as  $value){

        if ($value % 2 == 0)
        {
            $return_evn_array[] = array($value);

        }
        else 
        {
            $return_odd_array[] = array($value);

        }

    }
    return  array('evn_array' => $return_evn_array, 'odd_array' =>$return_odd_array);

}
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r(getEvens($ints));
 echo '</pre>';
?>
```